# Opening layers panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers

I closed the layers panel and don't know how to open it back up.

Could someone give me a simple explanation as to which tab it is located on so I can open it back up?

Answer (score 6):

View menu, Panels... Layers

that should restore it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using QGIS Desktop, go to View -> Panel -> Layer Order.

Comment: Or just Layers, not Layer Order.